# Textbox and cell linking

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm using Office 2010. I am writing a VBA macro in Excel where I want a text box (say TextBox 2) to have a value equal to the value of a cell. The cell is not known beforehand.

I used the following snippet:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2").Characters.Text = Cells(LastCellRowNumber, 9).Value
```

where `LastCellRowNumber` will be given as an input.

When I run this code, it gives an "object does not support this property or method" error.
Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for what you need is as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cells(LastCellRowNumber, 9).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Record Macro is your friend:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Cells(LastCellRowNumber, 9).Value
```

At least in my excel, but I see that different versions have different properties